Does WebStorm have "auto save: afterDelay" as VS Code does?
Does it have "auto save: afterDelay" or something similar because I am getting annoyed by WebStorm poor auto saving and refreshing HTML document.
For example... I have canvas with height 500px (500px height) and than I want to change it to the height of 600px but this happens (600px height)  because WebStorm saw that I erased number 5 and now he registered height="00" and when I type 6 back in place it obviously does not register that until next keyboard input. I have three options : refresh the webpage, click on the webpage to see the result of change or wait cca. 7-8sec for WebStorm to automatically do autosave (and also refreshes webpage).
VS Code never had similar problems because he has (I guess?) "auto save: afterDelay" so whatever I change in document it saves 0,5sec or 1sec later so it updates the webpage pretty quickly.
I tried going into settings and play around with:

"File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Live Edit"
"File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings -> Autosave"

Also searched on Google how to speed up WebStorm a little bit.
Can it be because my laptop is too slow or something similar?
Yeah also I am student and have free version of WebStorm so I wanted to use it a bit to see how it works because I have been using VS for past two months and as I am going through the lections I am constantly changing small things like this example above so I hope you understand my frustrations.

Any File Watchers that watch over such file? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-file-watchers.html  They have an option to run the command immediately and not wait for the valid syntax or on save only. Double check that. Cannot say about this Live Edit preview thingy -- do not use it, so not sure what config it may have.

While WebStorm has auto-save functionality, it triggers automatically upon various events like switching applications, compiling code or being idle for a period. There's no built-in option to set a specific delay after making changes.

Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | Save files if the IDE is idle for.
